# How do I Hide an element in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to control the `data-toggle = 'collapse'` with Angular JS

I have something like

```
<a href="#" ng-click="clickMe()"

<div id="wrapper"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#test">
   texts and elements...
</div>

<div id='test'>
    test div….
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.clickMe = function() {
      //I want to collapse the test div in angularjs when I click the <a> tag.
      //I can archive that by using the codes below but I want to use the angular          
      //way to do this 
      $('#test').collapse('hide')
}
```

How do I do it in Angular way? Thanks!

Comment: The less jQuery you use the better. switching from regular twitter bootstrap to angular bootstrap is a big win
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

You could use ng-show to do this and have ng-click toggle a scope variable.

```
<div ng-click="test1Showing=!test1Showing">
   texts and elements...
</div>

<div ng-show='test1Showing'>
    test div….
</div>
```

Or if you want to remove the element, not just display:none; you can use ng-if instead of ng-show.